# how to start mongodb daemon in python

Tags: python, mongodb, subprocess

how can I start the mongodb daemon in python?  I have the following script

```
    import subprocess

    subprocess.Popen(['C:\\mongodb\\bin\\mongod', '----dbpath C:\\dropbox\\projects\\mongodb'])
```

and I get this error:

**error command line: unknown option --dbpath C:\dropbox\projects\mongodb**

The mongo database is already created in C:\dropbox\projects\mongodb\

I can move the mongo database to c:\ and not specify the '--dbpath' and it works fine. I can also run mongod from the windows shell with the specified '--dbpath' and it runs fine.

For some reason when I try to run it from python it does not like the '--dbpath' argument being passed to it.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split `'--dbpath C:\\dropbox\\projects\\mongodb'`, it should be `'--dbpath', 'C:\\dropbox\\projects\\mongodb'`. There are two independent command line parameters, not one, they are grouped logically by mongodb args parsing code. And it should be `--dbpath`, not `----dbpath`, at least on Linux it is.

**UPD:** Your original code executes `mongod` like this:

```
C:\\mongodb\\bin\\mongod "----dbpath C:\\dropbox\\projects\\mongodb"
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks a bunch!  I knew it had to be simple.  I just didn't see it should be independent args.

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to accept my answer if it was useful (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow for info on how that works). :-D